# I have a problem with a component Datatable

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon,

I ve found my self for a long time try to found my mistake, but i don't haved lucky. I  fallowed the indications to work with Datatable of this website: https://datatables.net/

The Datatable component does not work at all. I appreciate so much any help about it.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All you've done is load the DataTables library.  You never actually used it.  The page to which you link has an example for initializing the table right there in the introduction, as well as a link to their more detailed "getting started" guide.

Comment: As @David said: `$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );`